# I want to compare 2 dates and make if else

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In a Google Sheet I want to compare two dates and check if either one (Plan start date, actual start date) is blank. It should show the text "not started" then. If not `if(plan start date <Actual start date)` show as Delay else "Inline":

`=if((DAYS360(D8,C8)<0,"Delay","Inline",IF(ISBLANK(D8),"Not started")))`

This didn't work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you have some syntax glitches. `IF ( condition, result if true, result if false )` is the proper syntax. You have 4 parameters at some level.

Comment: I have 2 conditions .*  IF(ISBLANK(D8) and if((DAYS360(D8,C8)<0)

Comment: I think (hope) I get what you want. Please see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF(DAYS360(D8;C8)<0;"Delay";IF(ISBLANK(D8);"Not started";"Inline"))
```

Use semicolons in Excel, not commas. Also, the IF conditionals are written like this:

```
=IF(condition; value if true; value if false)
```

If you write more than 3 parameters it just won't work. You can put an IF inside of a value parameter so you nest two IFs (or as many as you wish)

EDIT: ok I thought it was an Excel and not a google spreadsheet. Maybe there you can use commas. The rest is the same though, you had a mistake in the IF statement. `=IF(DAYS360(D8;C8)<0,"Delay",IF(ISBLANK(D8);"Not started","Inline"))` should do the work.

Comment: But it's not Excel. ;)

Comment: But nobody knew 2 minutes ago ;)

Comment: That's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
=if(
    (
        DAYS360(D8,C8)<0,
        "Delay",
        "Inline",
        IF(
            ISBLANK(D8),
            "Not started"
        )
    )
  )
```

Your outer `IF` has 4 arguments, while [the proper syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) is: `IF( condition, result if true, result if false)` and the 3rd argument is optional.

EDIT: As far as I understand, you might want to achive something like this:

```
IF(
    OR(ISBLANK(C8), ISBLANK(D8)),
    IF(
        ISBLANK(C8),
        "first is blank",
        "second is blank"
    ),
    "none of them is blank"
)
```

And in the "none of them is blank" case you may want to place an additional IF examining `DAYS360(C8, D8)`.